# Why is $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ closed in the rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

One definition for closedness as I understand it is that a set is closed iff it contains all its limit points. However, $1/\sqrt{2}$ is a limit point of a sequence of rationals in $[0,1]$, yet $1/\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$. This seems to suggest that the set is not closed.

More generally I am confused about how a set can be closed in a particular space, when the definition above makes no reference to this space. The same can be said for the definition "closed iff coincides with closure". The closure of $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1] = [0,1]$, no?

Comment: Remember the definition (or the proof of: depending on how you studied it) of "closed" in the **inherited** topology: if $\;X\;$ is a top. space and $\;Y\subset X\;$ with the inherited topology, then $\;B\subset Y\;$ is closed **in** $\;Y\;$ iff it is of the form $\;B=Y\cap K\;$ , with $\;K\;$ closed **in** $\;X\;$ ...

Comment: $1/\sqrt{2}$ is not a limit point of the rationals *in the rationals*. How could it be? It doesn't exist. For it to be a limit point, the rationals need to live inside a larger set that contains $1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: topooical notions in $\mathbb{Q}$ are usually considered as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is of the form "closed set in the total space intersected with subspace" and such sets are exactly the closed sets in the subspace by definition.

Your sequence argument only shows that it is not sequentially compact (so not compact), while $[0,1]$ is, nor complete. In $\mathbb{R}$ the closure would be $[0,1]$ but closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ means something else, namely a set of the form $C \cap \mathbb{Q}$ where $C \subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is closed.

To show non-closedness (in $\mathbb{Q}$!) of a set $C \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ you need a $q \in \mathbb{Q}, q\notin C$ such that there is a sequence $c_n \in C$ with $c_n \rightarrow q$. But your $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \notin \mathbb{Q}$

As a final alternative:
You could consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as a set in itself, and use the metric $d(p,q) = |p-q|$ for $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$. But then you cannot talk about points outside $\mathbb{Q}$. To see closedness of your set:suppose $q_n \rightarrow q$,$q \in \mathbb{Q}$ where all $q_n \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. Then $q \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ as well, as $q > 1$ means we can take $\varepsilon = q -1 >0$ to get a contradiction with the convergence, and if $q <0 $ we take $|q| > 0$ instead.
(Or use your knowledge of $\mathbb{R}$ (sneaky) and conclude that way that $q \in [0,1]$, as all $q_n$ are too.) But you can show it entirely inside the rationals, if you're a purist.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing closure and sequence closure, which are not the same. If they happen to be the same, the space is called a "Fréchet–Urysohn space" or in short FU (not joking). Let $(X,\tau)$ by a topological space, then $A \subseteq X$ is defined to be closed iff $X\setminus A$ is open (in $\tau$).

Now lets look at $ \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] $ in $\mathbb{Q}$:

$$\mathbb{Q} \setminus \left (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \right ) = \mathbb{Q} \cap \left ( (-\infty , 0) \cup (1,\infty) \right ) $$

All of these are open in $\mathbb{Q}$ so the result is open too, making the original set close.

QED.

Answer (score 1):

The concepts of "closed set" and "closure" **always** exists in a particular space. The definition of closed set and the definition of closure refers to the space, and every single usage of those concepts refers to the space.

Sometimes the reference is suppressed, and the space is implicit, because the space is clear from the larger context.

For example, suppose you are reading the definition of closure in a textbook. Here, for clarity, I will use the more basic definition of closure, not the sequence definition in your question. The book might have a passage saying something like this:

- Let $X$ be a topological space BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH [lots of intervening stuff making you forget the context] BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH. The closure of a set $C$ is equal to the intersection of all closed sets containing $C$.

Notice, by the time this passage gets around to discussing the definition of the closure, $X$ is nowhere in sight. So, you may wish to be more explicit about the space, and if so then you could translate the passage for yourself like this:

- Let $X$ be a topological space [forget all the intervening stuff]. The closure of a subset $C$ of $X$ is equal to the intersection of all closed subsets of $X$ containing $C$.

Comment: To be even more precise in your final bullet, one might say "the $X$-closure" or "the closure in $X$" rather than just "the closure".

Comment: I like your second wording, but your first is not at all common so I would avoid that.